# How to make Windows 10 start menu look more like windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

[Win10 taskbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etdVr.png)

With some tweaking, I managed to make win 10 taskbar more like win 7. There is no need to a big search bar if you can start typing to search, right?. I deleted all the apps from it, so it looks much more clear but I still can't get it to shrink. I could use a win7 theme but I prefer the material theme of win 10.
[Only seeing this would be much more clear and more healthy for my eyes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIdHw.png)
Thanks for any help.

Comment: There are third-party start menu applications that make it behave like Windows 7.  Have you tried one of the *many* options that exist?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. Win10 already has a super easy way to shrink or hide the search icon and most other icons on it. What about the Windows 7 taskbar are you trying to replicate while retaining Win10'a material theming?

Comment: I only need to resize the start menu to minimum, but there is a minWidth set so it can't resize under one column. It's super annoying to install and configure a new theme just to minimize a single column, thank you microsoft.

Comment: The screenshot you're showing is *not* taskbar, that's Start Menu.

Comment: Yeah, sory for the mistake.